# Remove Text From Div Footer

Tags: html, css

I paid for this webstore, it is hosted by the company I just pay an annual fee. I want them to remove my cell phone number out of the footer and they want $50 because this is considered a customization. I am fairly familiar with HTML and CSS. I have tried a few things. They only give you access to the stylesheets and images. I cannot access anything else. Any way to remove my address and phone number? Any ideas?

```
  <div id="footer">Copyright Store Name 123 Street Parkway PA, 18222 5781236546</div>
```

current css:

```
  #footer {
            position: relative;
            top: 0px; left: 14px;
            width: 903px; height: 43px;
            background-color:#1a508a;
            text-align:center;
            line-height: 43px;
            color:#ffffff;
```

I have tried after and content with the css seems not to work.

I did display:none then put a background image of what I want to show. Only remedy I can see possible.

Comment: `#footer{display:none;}`

Comment: `#footer{font-size: 0} #footer:after{content: 'Custom text'; font-size: 1em}`

Comment: Another possibility is #footer {background-color:#x; color:#x;} Same color for both background and the text color

Comment: have you tried set none on display ? 
#footer{display:none;}

Comment: That's some screwed up company.

Comment: he already mention     display: none not working, thats weird

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#footer{
   display: none;
}
```

This will hide the footer. Hope it helps!